# Style a table row if one of its column attributes is true

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

I'm filling an HTML table with data from the following query:

```
$content_downloads = mysql_query( "SELECT 
     s.site, s.machine, d.projectid, d.directorySize, d.connectivityError, 
     d.blocked, d.blockedBy, d.blockedSince, d.errorString, d.dashboardTimeStamp 
     FROM rtcdb.site_machines s 
     LEFT JOIN rtcdb.downloadstatuses d 
     on (s.site = d.site and s.machine = d.machine)             
     where s.site in (select d2.site from rtcdb.downloadstatuses d2 
     where  d2.dashboardTimeStamp > (SELECT DATE_ADD(max(dashboardTimeStamp),INTERVAL -1 DAY)  
     from rtcdb.downloadstatuses)) order by s.site, s.machine asc", $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

This query is going into an HTML table based on the following HTML/PHP:

```
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Site</th>
                        <th>Machine</th>
                        <th>Project ID</th>
                        <th>Folder Size</th>
                        <th>Error Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($content_downloads)) {
                            $error_string = "";
                            if ($row["connectivityError"] == true ) {
                                $error_string = "COULD NOT CONNECT: " . $row["errorString"];
                            }
                            elseif ($row["blocked"] == true ) {
                                $error_string = "BLOCKED BY LOCK OWNED BY: " . $row["blockedBy"] . " " . $row["blockedSince"];
                            }

                            echo '
                                <tr>
                                    <td>'.$row["site"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["machine"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["projectid"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$row["directorySize"].'</td>
                                    <td style = "text-align: left; color: red;">'.$error_string.'</td>
                                </tr> ';
                            }
                        ?>
                </tbody>
        </table>
```

The error description column in this table rarely has contents. As you can see, when it does, a PHP conditional function (the if and ifelse functions) places a statement before the error description to make the description more understandable. One thing you may notice is that I am coloring the text of error descriptions red. The thing that I am struggling with that I need your help on is to selectively style an entire row with a background-color of yellow, when the error description cell in that row has a value. In other words, when the two conditionals I wrote are true, I would like to make the background-color of the row that includes that error description yellow.

It seems pretty simple, but I have tried various options and can't seem to figure it out. Any tips Stack Overflow?

Comment: Have you looked into using jQuery?

Comment: Nope, what sort  of jQuery method should I look into?

Comment: Using jQuery to style static content is like using a screwdriver to hammer a nail.

Comment: yup... too much reliance on jQuery (etc) these days... a site should still function and display if I turn JS off :) if it doesn't it's a broken site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the error string is empty:

```
echo '
    <tr' . (empty($error_string) ? '' : ' style="background-color:yellow;"') . '>
        <td>'.$row["site"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["machine"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["projectid"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["directorySize"].'</td>
        <td style = "text-align: left; color: red;">'.$error_string.'</td>
    </tr> ';
```

Comment: I updated this to highlight the row.  As an aside, this will solve your problem but you should look into using CSS instead of inline styling, as @Marc suggested in his answer.

Comment: You could update your example code and replace the style attributes with class attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the yellow background color isn't showing up in those rows :(

Comment: @jakelaz I just realized there was a typo (missing a space).  This will work now.

Answer (score 2):

What I would try is setting a class on the row of interest:

```
<tr class="highLight">
```

and then use CSS to set the background color of the cells in that row:

```
tr.highLight td {background-color: yellow; }
```

Set the class attribute is your error string has content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($error_string != "")
 {
   echo '<tr class="error-row"';
 }else{
   echo '<tr>';
 }
 echo    '<td>'.$row["site"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["machine"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["projectid"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["directorySize"].'</td>
         <td style = "text-align: left; color: red;">'.$error_string.'</td>
         </tr> ';
```

and add this to your stylesheet:

```
.error-row{background:yellow;}
```

if you want less code you can use the if shorthand too like this:

```
echo   '<tr' . ($error_string == "" ? '' : 'class="error-row"') . '>
          <td>'.$row["site"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["machine"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["projectid"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["directorySize"].'</td>
          <td style = "text-align: left; color: red;">'.$error_string.'</td>
        </tr> ';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it seems like it should work, but I keep getting this error message:  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\DownloadStatus.php on line 415" Any ideas why its not working?

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful David

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what to do, and I apologize for not using jQuery or class attributes. I appreciate everyones help, and am being honest when I say that everyone's comments and answers helped me figure it out. Here's the solution:

```
                            if ($error_string != ""){
                                echo '
                                    <tr style = "background-color: yellow;">
                                        <td>'.$row["site"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$row["machine"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$row["projectid"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$row["directorySize"].'</td>
                                        <td style = "text-align: left; color: red;">'.$error_string.'</td>
                                    </tr> ';
                                }
                            else {
                                echo '
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>'.$row["site"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$row["machine"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$row["projectid"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$row["directorySize"].'</td>
                                        <td style = "text-align: left; color: red;">'.$error_string.'</td>
                                    </tr> ';
                                }
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: You should take a look at my answer again.  I had a small typo.  The way you are doing it here causes a lot of code duplication which will make it very hard to maintain.